# matlab array subsetting by indices

Tags: matlab, indexing, subset

Let's say I have a 3x3x3 Matlab array with members 1 to 27

`a=reshape(1:27, [3 3 3])`

I would like to create a subset of this with a syntax like

`b=a(range1,range2,range3)`

where for range1=range2=range3=1:2 I would get the members `b(1,1,1)` and `b(2,2,2)`. i.e

`b= [1 14]`

Is it possible to do this just with indexing and without any functions (e.g. diag)? Thanks...

Comment: @Parag, sub2ind requires same size vectors for ranges. For example `b=a(sub2ind(size(a),range1,range2,1:3))`. That's why I am looking for doing it only with the indices...

Comment: @Molly please see my comment to Parag above...

Comment: range1, range2, and range3 have to be the same size because each corresponds to a dimension of the matrix a. For example, if range1 = [x1,x2,x3], range2 = [y1,y2,y3] and range3 = [z1,z2,z3] the values obtained will be a(x1,y1,z1), a(x2,y2,z2) and a(x3,y3,z3). So it wouldn't make sense for this function to take different sized vectors. In the example in your comment, what to do expect the answer to be?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with `sub2ind` function as follows:

```
b=a(sub2ind(size(a),range1,range2,range3))

ans: b=[1 14]
```

Comment: sub2ind requires same size vectors for ranges. For example `b=a(sub2ind(size(a),range1,range2,1:3))`. That's why I am looking for doing it only with the indices...

Comment: If they are of same size, say 1:2, 1:2, 1:3, then how will you decide subscripts. Because when they are of equal size 1:2, subscripts will be (1,1,1) and (2,2,2)

Answer (score 1):

The indexing can be done using `sub2ind`,

```
a(sub2ind(size(a),[1:2],[1:2],[1:2]))
```

if you want to avoid all functions, you could calculated the linear indices yourself...